# How to link boost.build project to particular static library

Tags: c++, boost-build

I use boost.build for my project. Of course, I use boost itself. Also, for test purposes I use google-test library with my project. I have to link my project with google-test's static library. I've found the workaround to do that for MinGW (for linux's gcc works too)

```
exe foo : $(IMPORTANT_PART) $(TEST_UTILITY_PART) : <toolset>gcc <linkflags>"../../libs/gtest-1.6.0/libs/gtest_main.a" <linkflags>-static <linkflags>-lpthread ;
```

It looks kind of ugly but it works. The rule for msvc looks much much more ugly

```
exe foo : $(IMPORTANT_PART) $(TEST_UTILITY_PART) : <toolset>msvc <linkflags>/LIBPATH:../../libs/gtest-1.6.0/libs <linkflags>/DEFAULTLIB:gtest_main-mdd.lib
<linkflags>/DEFAULTLIB:gtestd-md.lib
;
```

Is there more natural way to link target with external static library in boost.build project file.

---

P.S. Of cource using google-test and boost mix smells not good, but anyway there are a lot of external libraries that cover areas boost doesn't cover.

TIA

Comment: At least it is possible to make Jamroot for google-test and link my project to this new one with use-project statement. And use boost linking feature. But the question how to link external static library is still open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great! Thank the persond who pointed me http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/prebuilt.html page. (the comment disappeared) It seems to be, I did read this page not carefully. And target lib with file property does the thing I searched for. Thanks!

---

As for using google test and boost build I did this way: I made Jamfile for google-test. It is very simple:

```
gtest.lib/Jamfile
    project gtest_main 
         : requirements <include>../../../libs/gtest-1.6.0/include
                        <include>../../../libs/gtest-1.6.0/
         : source-location ../../../libs/gtest-1.6.0 
         : build-dir ../../../libs/gtest-1.6.0/bin.b2 ; 
    
    lib gtest_main : src/gtest_main.cc src/gtest-all.cc : <link>static ;
```

Then, somewhere in my project file:

use-project /gtest : ./gtest.lib ;

and mentioning //gtest in project's requirements section.